# Can I transit in Japan as a non-revenue passenger?

Tags: usa, japan, transit-visas, filipino-citizens

I am a Filipino citizen residing in Virginia. I am planning to visit the Philippines as a non-revenue passenger from Dallas to Japan, but I also have a paid ticket from Japan to the Philippines. Do I still need a Japanese transit visa?

Thanks.

Comment: What is "non-reving"?

Comment: @fkraiem its a slang other people use, mostly airline employees. It means you are a chance passenger or you're using a buddy pass. Short for non-revenue passenger.

Comment: Are your flights to/from the same airport and on the same calendar day?

Comment: I would be very surprised if the fact of being a non revenue passenger made any difference to immigration requirements.

Comment: @jpatokal Well, lets just say that my potential flight plan would be flying out from Dallas, TX on the  22nd then arriving to Narita, Japan on the 23rd then my flight to the Philippines would be 2-3 hours after my arrival to Japan. That means I don't need to go out of immigration anymore.

Comment: @user16259 Same thoughts but I've been seeing some forums that require you to have transit visa either way. Thats why im confused.

Comment: @JoseIñigo Requiring a transit visa "either way" is the same as not making any difference to immigration ...

Comment: @AzorAhai I'm sorry but I do not follow you. Are you saying that I still do need to acquire a transit visa?

Comment: I have never had to acquire one, so I'm not an expert, but user16259 said they don't know why being non-rev would make any difference to immigration (and I agree). You said some forums say you are required to have a visa either way. I assumed by "either way" you meant either as a regular or non-rev passenger. Did you mean something else?

Comment: OP has not returned to clarify comments/questions.  Putting on hold for now.